# How to mass change the link in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, dns

the thing is, In my WordPress website i have posted some links to some post. and the domain name of the links have been changed and they are so much in an amount in total of 549 posts.the link is like this yourdomain.com/free-access/ and they are in a button. so any suggestions how can i change the domain name.

thanks

Comment: Check out the tool [search and replace db 3](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Comment: can you share both old and new url?

Comment: thanks for the help guys, I end up using Better Search and replace plugin to change the link. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a global search and replace with a plugin. There are others but I suggest **Better Search and Replace**. It's in the WordPress Repository and is free.

Before you make a change like this you should run a full backup, just in case anything goes wrong.

The plugin in question will let you do a dry run, that is you enter your search text and replace text, select the tables you want to search in and then check the box to Run as Dry Run. This will show you where your changes would be made without actually making them, so you're sure you've entered the right search and replace terms.

You can also make changes like this directly on the database tables using SQL but I strongly recommend against it. This tool is much safer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to change the domain names in posts is to export and download the database backup. Search and replace the domain name occurrences and save the sql file. Then import the sql file.